# In flutter, how to trigger something strictly after an async function is done executing?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

Say I have a `_mode` property that I want to change in `setState()` when a button is pressed.

When the button is pressed (`onPressed`), I am calling this function,

```
Future <void> changeMode() async {
    _result = await getResult(); // Returns a result. I want the mode to change AFTER the result is returned
    setState((){
         _mode = Modes.OFF; 
    });
}
```

What ends up happening is, the `_mode` is changed before the `getResult()` is done executing. How should I go fixing this?

Comment: mark the `changeMode` as async.

Comment: @AdnanAlshami tried that, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

When you use await inside a function, that function is in danger of blocking the main thread, so it must be marked as async.

Mark your function with `async` and it should work. Your state setting function also should be a parameter of `setState()`.

```dart
Future<void> changeMode() async {
    _result = await getResult(); // Returns a result. I want the mode to change AFTER the result is returned
    setState(() {     
      _mode = Modes.OFF;    
    });
}
```

Comment: Your `setState` also should be `setState(() {
    _mode = Modes.OFF; 
  });`

Comment: My bad, missed that while copying. It is `setState(() {     _mode = Modes.OFF;    });`

Comment: Try changing your await line with `await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));` and see if state changes after 5 seconds. If yes, then the issue is in your `getResult()`, otherwise somewhere outside of this specific function. It should work based on the data you've shared.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It indeed is my `getResult()` at fault

Comment: This explanation is wrong. `await` doesn't block the main thread. `await` isn't even legal syntax *without* marking a function as `async`, and the point of asynchronous functions is that they don't block. `await` is syntactic sugar for setting up a `Future.then` callback.

Comment: This doesn't mean that you can use `await` without `async`. Maybe this can give you a bit more of an explanation on this topic: https://flutterfix.com/flutter-future-await-and-async/

Comment: As I said, `await` *requires* `async`.  The "when you use await inside a function, that function is now in danger of blocking the main thread" claim in your answer and in the linked article is nonsense. `await` is syntactic sugar for using `Future.then`; it *always* yields and returns to the event loop.